# "ImportError: cannot import name 'styles' from 'gspread2'" when trying to create a .py program that will read my google sheet

Tags: python, excel, traceback

I read about *gspread2* and tried to give it a go.

I created the API credentials, and downloaded the JSON token.

I tried the following code to test if I could read from my target cell as a test:

```
from gspread2.models import Workbook

URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[REDACTED]'
CREDENTIALS = 'C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/REDACTED.json'

workbook = Workbook(URL, CREDENTIALS)

worksheet = workbook['Sheet 1']

selected_cell = worksheet.cell('B2')
print(selected_cell)
```

It throws me the traceback:

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'styles' from 'gspread2' 
> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gspread2\__init__.py)
> ```

- I have tried against python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 both from the microsoft store and from the python website. The same error.
- I have also tried solutions from similar errors in other libraries and none of them worked.

I also checked the `__init.py__` file for instances of **styles** and it doesn't seem to have any.

I'm fairly new with coding, and I'm at a loss on what to do next.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.

Comment: Was the traceback message larger than that line?

Comment: As I read in doc: “Gspread2 is a wrapper around gspread”. Perhaps you don't have installed [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) automatically with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in gspread2's packaging which fails to bundle and install the `gspread2.styles` package. The source is on github [gspread2](https://github.com/futuereprojects/gspread2). This line in `setup.py` needs changing from

```
packages=['gspread2'],
```

to

```
packages=['gspread2', 'gspread2.styles'],
```

You may want to contact the authors. As for a temporary fix for now, you could download the package from github

```
git clone https://github.com/futuereprojects/gspread2
```

make the fix and then, in the gspread directory run, `python3 setup.py install`. Or find out where the packages is currently installed and copy the `styles` subdirectory into it.